# One long-lasting AJAX request and site switch within one PHP session

Tags: php, ajax, apache

### Introduction

I am writing a WordPress plugin, but I think it is more a PHP/Apache question. The WordPress plugin requests every 60 seconds (or at startup of each site) an AJAX call to the WordPress backend. If something conditional is true the request can be up to 20 seconds (depending on `max_execution_time`).

### The problem

Adopted the AJAX request now starts and the process takes 20 seconds, but now I want to switch the WordPress site **before the AJAX request is finished**. The site switch happens after the 20 seconds, but why? I am using Apache Server.

I hope it is well explained. :-)

Comment: Are you interested in why the same server answers the initial request, right? That happens because AJAX call keeps HTTP connection alive until the request is fulfilled. It cannot be passed to another server without some workaround.

Comment: Yes, and how is the workaround? :)

Comment: You need to decouple calling the server function and receiving results but it would seriously complicate your design. So rethink if you really need this.

Comment: Do you think about a cURL request in PHP and receiving the result by checking if the request has finished?

Comment: curl may work but it has one big disadvantage - you can't say whether the script is still working or it was abandoned and you should send request to another server. Note that you might resend the request endlessly in case of quick switching servers.

Comment: Ok, now i tried to use [wp_remote_get()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get) function to retrieve data from the own wordpress site. Now i get the following error: `Missing header/body separator` while i want to access the /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php . Do you have any experiences with that?

Comment: I think this is a flaw of design if it is needed to abandon script execution and switch to another server. Better find another solution for your problem.